# I want to convert C code block to equivalent PHP code

Tags: php

```
if (crc & 0x8000){
  crc = crc << 1 ^ 0x1021;
}
```

Above code block is in C language.
what would be the equivalent php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bitwise operators and inline hex numbers in PHP just fine. The equivalent should just be:

```
if ($crc & 0x8000){
  $crc = $crc << 1 ^ 0x1021;
}
```